# Import Material design library android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am trying to import the library.

I added it to the gradle script

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

If I open the project structure( control+shift+alt+s ) It is added on dependencies of the module. But If I try to write the import it doesnt appear.

There is a photo with the project dependencies, gradle script and the import now working

[image]

Comment: have you synced your gradle

Comment: Yes, I did it, I am using it on another project and it work fine, I just cant make it work on this one

Comment: Make sure your Android sdk updated up to 5.1.1(API 22).

Comment: The sdk say that It is updated with the last version

Comment: Which feature do you want use from material design?

Comment: The SnackBar and TextInputLayout feature ( but I want to use more in the future)

Comment: LoginActivity is in the same module in which you have declared dependency?

Comment: Yes it was in the same module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tryied to add a TextInputLayout on the xml file, eliminated the snackbar and tryied to compile it, After no error, it works, Now I can import the snackbar